# How to Convert PHP Array to a specific JSON Output Array

Tags: php, json

This is my array that I wants to convert

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/12/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 0
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

   [1] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/11/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 0
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

   [2] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/10/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 0
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

   [3] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/09/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 0
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

   [4] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/08/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 0
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

   [5] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/07/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 0
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

   [6] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/06/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 3729195
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

   [7] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/05/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 7458390
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

   [8] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/04/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 0
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

   [9] => stdClass Object
       (
           [Item1] => 10/03/2021
           [Item2] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 0
                   [1] => 0
                   [2] => 0
                   [3] => 0
               )

       )

)
```

I wants this array output like this -

```
[{name:"", data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,3729195,7458390,0,0]},
{name:"", data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
{name:"", data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
{name:"", data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}]
```

The problem is that the first element of [Item2][0] input array is the first elements of each 4 rows of data:[0] and second element of [Item2][1] is second column of each data set of data[1] elements of all 4 rows, I hope you understand what I mean.

And the dates should be in another separate list like this -

```
['10/12/2021', '10/11/2021', '10/10/2021', '10/09/2021', '10/08/2021', '10/07/2021', '10/06/2021', '10/05/2021', '10/04/2021', '10/03/2021'],
```

I have already done some tests and here is what I did so far -

```
$ChartDataNew  = stripcslashes(trim(json_encode($jobs->charts_last10days), "\""));

$replace1 = str_replace('Item1', name, $ChartDataNew);
$replace2 = str_replace('Item2', data, $replace1);
print_r($replace2);
```

The above code is giving me output of an JSON object

```
[{"name":"10/12/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/11/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/10/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/09/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/08/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/07/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/06/2021","data":[3729195,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/05/2021","data":[7458390,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/04/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/03/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]}]
```

This JSON seems ok, but its not correct. First of all I wants to make the JSON output as given above without "" and name should be name:"". When you see the data in output of my json object is not matching to date in input array.

To get the list of dates I have done this and its fine -

```
$chartDataSeries = array();
$chartDateLabels = array();
$chartSeriesList = array();
foreach($jobs->charts_last10days as $chartData){
array_push($chartDateLabels, "'".$chartData->Item1."'");
array_push($chartDataSeries, $chartData->Item2);         
           
} 

$chartDateLabels1 = implode(', ', ($chartDateLabels));
echo ($chartDateLabels1);
```

Its giving me the correct output for list of dates, see

```
['10/12/2021', '10/11/2021', '10/10/2021', '10/09/2021', '10/08/2021', '10/07/2021', '10/06/2021', '10/05/2021', '10/04/2021', '10/03/2021']
```

please let me know what I am doing wrong or help me out how to do that, may be write some functions or any other way to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome. You need to do the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_, post your attempt, explain where you're stuck and what currently happens. We're here to help you with concrete issues with your current code, not to write it all for you (which a proper answer here would require us to)

Comment: Hi, @MagnusEriksson Thanks for your reply but I already did some tests and see what I did ``` $ChartDataNew  = stripcslashes(trim(json_encode($jobs->charts_last10days), "\""));

        $replace1 = str_replace('Item1', name, $ChartDataNew);
        $replace2 = str_replace('Item2', data, $replace1);
        print_r($replace2); ```

Comment: Then I got this Then I got this output `[{"name":"10/12/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/11/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/10/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/09/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/08/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/07/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/06/2021","data":[3729195,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/05/2021","data":[7458390,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/04/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]},{"name":"10/03/2021","data":[0,0,0,0]}]`  but this is not correct one, so that's why I am here to get some help to figure it out.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69544992/edit) your question to include additional information instead of spreading it out in comments. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but the easiest way I could think of was using iterating through each element, and then constructing another array:

```php
$resultArr = [];

// Iterate over each element of the original array
foreach ($dataArr as $key => $arr) {
    // Set the date
    $datesArr[$key] = $arr->Item1;

    // Iterate over each element of Item2
    foreach ($arr->Item2 as $i => $v) {
        // Set 'data' on the resulting array item $i to the value
        //  using the $key from the outer loop as the index for the inner data array
        $resultArr[$i]['data'][$key] = $v;

        // Set the name
        $resultArr[$i]['name'] = '';
    }
}

// Convert from an array to JSON
echo json_encode($resultArr) . PHP_EOL;

// The dates are in $datesArr
echo json_encode($datesArr) . PHP_EOL;
```

`$dataArr` is the variable where your data is currently stored. After running this loop, `$resultArr` will be an array, of which each element is another array containing the data in the right format, and `$datesArr` is the dates from the data in their own array.

Comment: Hi @NerdOfLinux Thanks for your help. It's all what I was looking for and the rest of work I did some changes according to my requirements and it worked fine, I really appreciate your time and help. Thanks Again :)